# Android SQLite get all rows where column contains string always returns -1

Tags: java, android, sqlite

textAs the title describes I'm trying to get all rows from a table where strings of a column contains a string anywhere in it. But they way I'm doing it now always return -1 rows.
This is how i'm doing it now but I have no idea of what I might be doing wrong. Suggestions?

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_RECENT, null, DBHelper.COLUMN_TEXT+ " LIKE '%"+club_id+"%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: There's no such thing as returning -1 rows. What's the specific problem? Any exception? How are you using the returned cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write `cursor.moveToFirst();` before getting data from cursor or just under query line.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Not yet, I tried entreco's response and got an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
But the cursor has -1 rows so moveToFirst isn't working either.

Comment: have you check your cursor value??? or also check cursor.getcount() value @just_user

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're mis interpreting the structure of query. the second parameter is what you want to select. such as "select **column1, column2** etc. Here's a line from my code, and it works for me.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(table_employees, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME,KEY_DEPARTMENT, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, KEY_SALARY}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

here "new string[] {key_id.....", the second parameter, is column names, that you wanted to select.

**OR**

alternately, you may simply do as:

```
String query = "Select * from "+DB_TABLE+ "Where" +column1 + "=" + t +"and"+ column2 + "=" +tt
db.rawQuery(query);
```

Comment: Query is perfect in question.

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like,

```
String query = "Select * FROM Product where name LIKE '%" + Text + "%'"
Log.d("search query", query);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
c.moveToFirst();
```